# Why don't all states mandate vehicle inspections?

Tags: united-states, law, transportation

How and why do certain states (e.g. Florida, Michigan) not mandate that every vehicle go through an annual inspection check? For $50 per vehicle per year - 1) it ensures all the clunkers and risky cars are off the roads so it keeps the driving public safer and 2) it provides a cash injection to the auto mechanic industry. I think this should be enforced at a federal level and individual states should not be allowed to remove this. It's a win-win all for just $50.

[image]

Comment: Okay then how about if your car is more than x (7?) years old then you should do it.  I see some very questionable things on 4 wheels in Michigan and I think it's the governments responsibility to remove these cars so as not to put anyone at risk.  Also what about the number of deaths and injuries caused by clunkers that were questionable in their road friendliness.  Isn't that a loss of economic potential activity?  A study ought to be done here

Comment: The sounds like a proposal more than a question.

Comment: This was introduced at the county level in Miami-Dade, later it had to be removed because of huge corruption problems. That is, you had to bribe the mechanic to pass the inspection even if your car was flawless.

Comment: Worth noting: There's both **emissions checks** and **safety inspections**, which are often combined in the states that require both.  Some states just require one or the other.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_inspection_in_the_United_States) for a map.

Answer (score 5):

> *How and why do certain states (eg Florida, Michigan) not mandate that every vehicle go through an annual inspection check?*

The ultimate political reason why all states don't mandate it is because a majority of the citizens of those states don't want those inspections (or rather, don't put enough pressure so that a majority of their state legislature wants to vote for them).

Why is that?

Well, for one thing, because your blaze "It's a win-win all" is a false statement.

It's a loss to every single one of millions of people forced to shell $50 to auto mechanic industry for no benefit to themselves since they drive non-"clunkers and risky cars". Also, for most normal people, inspection also takes a fair bit of time - so add up another $50-$500 economic impact from time expenditure on passing the inspection depending on how much an hour or 2 of your time costs.

.

---

> *I think this should be enforced at a federal level and individual states should not be allowed to remove this.*

This runs counter to the [Tenth Amendment of the US Constitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)

(*admittedly, there are easy ways around that which have been repeatedly used by US Federal Government on numerous issues, including indirect pressure (withdrawing highway funds) and declaring assorted things to be "interstate commerce"*)

.

.

---

Additionally, proponents of such a proposal need to show a clear benefit - does introducing the mandatory inspection meaningfully reduce the risks?

- There may not necessarily to be all that many real clunkers (at the very least, your question didn't provide any evidence to that effect).

  Preponderance of images on social internets is more indicative of the fact that they are fun to take photos of and make fun of, than actual frequency.
- Car age may not necessarily imply bad condition.

  <sub>Anecdotally, I personally drive a >15 year old car and it is safer (runs well, easily passed inspection, and is well maintained :) than many other cars on the road judging by latter new cars' dents and scratches</sub>
- Behavior of the driver is a lot more impactful risk factor.
- Most people driving **real** clunkers wouldn't care about your "inspection" requirements anymore than they care about obeying any other laws or rules. Like driving with valid drivers' licenses, insurance, etc...

  As usual, your law/regulation would negatively impact people who don't need it, and have no negative impact on those that do.
- And, even if you do have a "real" clunker that would have flunked the inspection, you need to first produce proof that taking it off the road would meaningfully reduce risk, given the costs to society and previous bullet points.

Comment: I don't agree with the OP's proposal, but one could certainly argue that there *is* a benefit to everyone in that unsafe cars are kept off the road (though as you point out, evidence of that would be important) Whether you are the one driving it or not is, alas, not always germane to whether you get hurt by it or not.

Comment: @DA. - that assertion requires some proof that the cars rejected by inspection are, in fact (a) unsafe and (b) the benefit of reducing that unsafety times # of rejected cars exceeds the negatives of the proposal.

Comment: I agree. My point was that assertion that it's a win-win for everyone requires as much proof as the assertion that "it's a loss to every single one of millions of people forced to shell $50". Both are assertions made that would need data to back them up. As for the tenth amendment, that doesn't really apply here any more than say federal car safety standards or speed limit conditions. So that's likely not the reason. I think your first paragraph, however, sums it all up quite nicely.

Comment: @DA. - no, not really. Having to pay $50 for no tangible benefit is an obvious loss. Also, why wouldn't 10th amendment apply? There's no interstate commerce issue (then again, in 2015, they can make me sneezing into interstate commerce, so whaddoIknow)

Comment: Benefits don't have to be tangible. As for the 10th, I doubt that is the reason here. There are all sorts of example of federal mandates pertaining to highways and vehicles.

Comment: The feds could *easily* get vehicle inspections required, seeing as how they got a 21-year-old drinking age passed for the same reason. You could argue it shouldn't be allowed, but it would be allowed. Just deny federal highway funds unless states ban uninspected vehicles from those highways.

Comment: @cpast - no disagreement with the last part. See the "sneezing" part of my answer for one way.

Answer (score 2):

Your two proposed benefits are dubious:

> It provides a cash injection to the auto mechanic industry.

Does the auto mechanic industry need a cash injection? [First Research](http://www.firstresearch.com/industry-research/Automotive-Repair-and-Maintenance-Services.html) profiles it as a $90 billion industry with high fragmentation and competition (good things). This doesn't even count the ubiquitous lube/oil change centers you see, since those are covered under a separate profile.

So the industry is doing just fine. There's no reason to artificially prop them up.

> It ensures all the clunkers and risky cars are off the roads so it keeps the driving public safer.

Even if it *did* ensure that (and I agree with DVK on this, it doesn't), what's the overall benefit, in terms of numbers?

A [2008 report by the NHTSA](http://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/Pubs/811059.PDF) showed that out of 5361 accidents they could assign a cause to, only 130 (2.4%) were caused by vehicle condition. An overwhelming majority of accidents (>5000) were caused by people, not clunky, unsafe vehicles.

In addition, for those accidents that *were* caused by vehicle condition, about 70% were attributed to tire/brake failure. Only 35 (0.7%) of 5361 crashes were caused by any other vehicle condition.

Bad tires and brakes are not normally what people consider "clunkers", at least in my area. While tires and brakes would be checked at a full-vehicle inspection, you could make it a much simpler 10-minute inspection without changing much.

---

In summary, you're proposing a massive system designed to funnel cash from consumers to an already thriving industry, for minimal safety benefits. This is ignoring all the other *potential* problems with it, such as corruption (which was a very real thing in my experience with Japanese inspections at least).

No thanks.